# How windows calculate file dimension?

Tags: c#, windows, file-io, dimension

I Calculate the binary size of a file with this function:

```
public static int BinarySize(string path)
        {
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);
            int hexIn;
            string ret = "";
            for (int i = 0; (hexIn = fs.ReadByte()) != -1; i++)
            {
                ret += Convert.ToString(hexIn, 2);

            }
            fs.Close();
            return ret.Length;
        }
```

An example of my problem is when I calculate the dimension of this simple black PNG image (10x10 pixels) [image: myImage]

With that function I find 640 bits => 80 bytes, but windows say that this file dimension is 136 byte.
Why this difference of 56 bytes? Is the security, permissions or some private information that windows attach to every file?

Comment: There is obviously a header for every file at the very least identifying the type of the file etc.

Comment: I use a similar function to read the hex of that file and starts with 89 50 4E 47 0D 0A 1A 0A that identify .png; the identification of that file is in that 80 bytes.

Answer (score 4):

`Convert.ToString(hexIn,2)` does not always return 8 characters, it trims leading zeroes, so if `hexIn` is `4`, it returns `100`, but not `00000100`.

You might want to change it to `Convert.ToString(hexIn,2).PadLeft(8, '0');`.
Also you'd want to use `StringBuilder` instead of `string` for `ret` variable.

By the way, reading file to determine its size is a bit wasteful. Better use [`FileInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) class to get file information.

Comment: Now i use Convert.ToString(hexIn, 2).PadLeft(8,'0'); and i find the right size. Thanks to solve my problem

Comment: Good answer (+1), but I'd mention `FileInfo` first, and definitely *not* as a "by the way"... it's the far more appropriate way to determine file size, and shouldn't be mentioned only as an aside.